# SwiftUI: No ObservableObject of type found. A View.environmentObject(_:)

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to understand why I keep getting

**No ObservableObject of type NodesArray found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for NodesArray may be missing as an ancestor of this view.**

when trying to pass data between views. I've searched through Stack but can't find an answer that seems to fit this particular scenario. The content of the array is displayed on initialization but doesn't get updated when the view is reloaded.

Update: The array is declared in SurfaceView but the actual code that displays the content of the array is NodeView.

```
class NodesArray: ObservableObject {

static let shared = NodesArray()
@Published var nodes = [(url: URL?, label: String, distance: Float)]()
```

...

```
func showDetailView() {
    let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: SurfaceView(mesh: .sampleMesh(), selection: .init()).environmentObject(NodesArray()))
    navigationController?.pushViewController(childView, animated: true)
}
```

...

```
class Mesh: ObservableObject {

@EnvironmentObject var array: NodesArray

let nodesArray = NodesArray.shared.nodes <------- Works but doesn't update after initialization

let newArray = mesh.array.nodes <-------------"No ObservableObject of type NodesArray found. A View.environmentObject(_:)....."

    nodesArray.forEach { (url, label, distance) in
    let point = mesh.pointWithCenter(center: .zero, radius: CGFloat(distance * 50), angle: CGFloat(distance))
    var node = mesh.addChild(mesh.rootNode(), at: point)
    node.text.append(label)
    node.distance = distance
    
    mesh.updateURL(node, url: url!)
    print(node)
}
return mesh
```

}
Updated:

```
struct SurfaceView: View {
  @ObservedObject var mesh: Mesh
  @ObservedObject var selection: SelectionHandler
    @EnvironmentObject var array: NodesArray
...

struct NodeView: View {
  static let width = CGFloat(300)
  // 1
  @State var node: Node
  //2
  @ObservedObject var selection: SelectionHandler
  //3
  var isSelected: Bool {
    return selection.isNodeSelected(node)
  }    
    
    var body: some View {
        ImageView(withURL: node.url!.absoluteString)
            .overlay(Text(String(format: "Value: %.1f", node.distance ?? 0.0)))
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(Circle()
                        .stroke(isSelected ? Color.red : Color.white, lineWidth: isSelected ? 7 : 5))
        

        }
    }


struct ImageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var imageLoader:ImageLoader
    @State var image:UIImage = UIImage()

    init(withURL url:String) {
        imageLoader = ImageLoader(urlString:url)
        print("reload")
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(uiImage: image)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
//                .frame(width:100, height:100)
        }.onReceive(imageLoader.didChange) { data in
            self.image = UIImage(data: data) ?? UIImage()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may help: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-fix-fatal-error-no-observableobject-of-type-sometype-found

Comment: Would you show code of SurfaceView? EnvironmentObject is for SwiftUI Views only - it does not work and does not make sense anywhere else.

Comment: ok, code updated